# weird error comming from Android SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

I'm getting a weird error in DDMS, it appears just after the innocent "Finalizing a Cursor that has not been deactivated or closed", comming from my own DataAdapter (about that in next question)

Error:

```
"Finalizing a Cursor that has not been deactivated or closed. database = /data/data/net.toload.main/databases/lime, table = null, query = SELECT _id, code, code3r, word, score FROM mapping WHERE code3r = '0'  AND code ='HTT'  ORDER BY cod"
```

I didn't create any tables with such columns in my app! And my localdatabase isn't stored there... /databases/lime, but this error seems to come just after my real error from my own DataAdapter. I tried to pull the lime.db file to read the contents of the database but the pulled file is always of 0 bytes, though on DDMS-FileExplorer is much more, now 26624bytes.

So ... im thinking that maybe android/google is tracking my every move!! and the app doesnt run in a isolated process...
Anyway can you explain this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your project must be using this `Lime IME (Lightweight Input Method Editor)`:

http://code.google.com/p/limeime/